# Why can't EVE get out of uncompressed garbage?

Tags: wall-e

At the start of the clip below, EVE appears to be struggling to come out of uncompressed garbage (e.g. *before* she gets 'cubed').

**Why can't she just fly out of the pile?**

Comment: Because she was stuck, duh :P

Comment: @Roberto BEFORE she was compressed, not after.

Answer (score 3):

She was still wearing her 'boot' (which is lit up, indicating that it's activated). A 'mouse' evidently reactivated her *consciousness*, but she was still physically disabled. It's only when she gets compacted that the boot is scraped off of her head and body and she's able to move again.

**Still wearing the boot.**
[image]

**Boot knocked off. Now able to move and (after a few seconds) extricate herself**.
[image]

---

Interestingly, the novelisation takes a slightly different tack, indicating that she was knocked unconscious *until* the compaction started.

> The giants each grabbed a ton of trash, cubed it, and rotated. They
> stacked their massive trash cubes on a platform, and the cubes slid on
> rails into an air lock. The huge air-lock doors started to close with
> a hiss. Then the exterior hatch flew open, the vacuum of space
> instantly pulling out the cubed trash.
>
> **When EVE awoke, she realized that she and WALL·E were squashed tightly
> inside two of the giant trash cubes.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Wall-E: Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3359002-wall-e-disney-pixar-wall-e)</sup></sub>